# Exception of my application published with clickone

Tags: c#, visual-studio, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

Good morning, I have a problem with an application written in C # and WinForms, which when published in clickone on the corporate network does not run. The installation process is normal, it creates the icon on the desktop, but when I click on it, the application does not run and I receive the following exception in the windows event viewer, which I do not understand where the error comes from.

```
    Aplicación: SEF.exe
Versión de Framework: v4.0.30319
Descripción: el proceso terminó debido a una excepción no controlada.
Información de la excepción: System.FieldAccessException
   en DevExpress.XtraEditors.WindowsFormsSettings..cctor()

Información de la excepción: System.TypeInitializationException
   en DevExpress.Skins.SkinManager..cctor()

Información de la excepción: System.TypeInitializationException
   en DevExpress.Skins.SkinManager.get_AllowFormSkins()
   en DevExpress.LookAndFeel.Design.ApplicationSettingsHelper.CheckSettings()
   en DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm..cctor()

Información de la excepción: System.TypeInitializationException
   en DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm..ctor()
   en SEF.formularios.frm_login..ctor()
   en SEF.Program.Main()
```

Comment: I removed the answer because it didn't resolve your issue. What is the error saying in English?

Comment: I try to translate into English, my mother tongue is Spanish.

The exception that my application registers when starting is the one in my initial question.

It only happens if I do the implementation via ClickOnce. If I copy the entire directory to the client computers, the application works correctly.

What could be happening?

Comment: @LOTIMJ, based on your description and the error, It seems that you may lose some dll or files in the included files. Please check if you included the related dll in the installation folder.

Comment: I would guess that you're missing the DevExpress.BonusSkins.vXX.X.dll library. Try changing all the Publish Status for all DevExpress dlls to Include. Check the Show all files checkbox to see some files that might not be visible otherwise.